# How create publishing page via CSOM or Powershell (SharePoint Online)

Tags: csom, publishing-page, provisioning, pnp-powershell

I would like to automate creation of a subsite and  of a publishing site.
Is it possible to create a publishing site and also dynamically add webparts to it e.g create also a document library on the fly and then add it to particular webpart zone

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
PublishingPageInformation publishingPageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation();
publishingPageInfo.Name = pageFileName // Set file name here;
publishingPageInfo.PageLayoutListItem = layout // Url of the page layout inside master page gallery;
// Adding new page to web.
PublishingPage publishingPage =pubWeb.AddPublishingPage(publishingPageInfo);
publishingPage.ListItem["Title"] = pageTitle; //title of the page
publishingPage.ListItem.Update();
_ctx.Load(publishingPage.ListItem);
_ctx.ExecuteQuery();
pageURL = publishingPage.ListItem["FileRef"].ToString(); // this will give you the URL of the page added
```

Don't forget to include `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing;` reference.

I hope this helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks users1100. About adding webparts dynamically to the page?